# Android-NDK-Add Native Support-NDK location not valid in preferences

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to use the debug mode 'Debug As' 'Android Native Application', the console says I need to add native support.

However, when I follow the instructions, it shows as the following picture:

[image]

What should I do with the 'NDK location not valid in preferences'?

Any advice would be helpful. I'm new on this. Thx.

- The sample is the NDK sample 'hello-jni'.

Comment: window -> preferences -> Android -> NDK -> from here browse the path to your android-ndk folder. Also to debug NDK stuff i suggest you to use DS-5 debugging tool.

Answer (score 12):

Check whether you have specified valid NDK locatioin in Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK