# Android NDK location not valid in preferences on MAC

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-ndk

This is my .profile:

```
export ANDROID_NDK="/Users/eduardoreis/Documents/workspace-support/android-ndk-r9"
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT="/Users/eduardoreis/Documents/workspace-support/android-ndk-r9"
export NDK="/Users/eduardoreis/Documents/workspace-support/android-ndk-r9"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_NDK"
```

And when I click in the option add Native Support it says:
 - NDK location not valid in preferences

And also, this Eclipse for some reason doesn't have Android>NDK>NDK_PTH (like on Windows OS)
[I already saw this, [Android-NDK-Add Native Support-NDK location not valid in preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122509/android-ndk-add-native-support-ndk-location-not-valid-in-preferences), but it is not my case] :/

Are my environment variables messed up or wrong?

Comment: Do you have CDT installed? Do you have the NDK plugin (included with ADT) installed? The NDK plugin is listed separately from the rest of the Developer Tools.

Comment: I had all this things installed.

Comment: Whoops, Problem solved. 
I didn't know that that option Android>NDK just appears when we go to ADT preferences... I was going to project>preferences.... 
It's embarrassing how silly the problem was... anyways... thanks... :)

Comment: You can make an answer with that information and accept it to wrap up your post :)

Comment: @krsteeve, thanks for suggest it. I'm still new on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.

I didn't know that that option Android>NDK just appears when we go to ADT preferences... I was going to project>preferences.